# mysql table to json

Tags: php, json

I am planning to use jQuery UI Autosuggest for a search form. So I need a json output which can be used by jQuery UI Auto suggest.

Here's the database [image]

Table name recent_tags

I have tried this

First connect to db

```
$do = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM recent_tags where query like '%" . $_GET['query'] . "%'"); 

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($fetch, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $row_array['query'] = $row['query'];
    array_push($return_arr,$row_array);
}

echo json_encode($return_arr);
```

but It's not working..

Please guide me..

EDIT :

getting error

> Warning: array_push() [function.array-push]: First argument should be an array in /pathto/my/file.php

Thanks

Comment: First, we need more information. What does "it's not working" mean? Any error messages, etc?

Comment: What is the error message you get? And what is the jquery code you use? BTW, don't forget to escape your $_GET["qery"], cause right now it is vulnerable for SQL injections.

Comment: Second, you really shouldn't pass user-provided vars ($_GET['qery'], for example) directly into a SQL string.

Comment: $_GET['qery'] is meant to be like that or should it be $_GET['query']

Comment: as you have given here
your result is in $do and you are running fetch on $fetch

Comment: @Ashwin Dhekane, I think it can be anything , as long as I use the same for making get request..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSON encode MySQL results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383631/json-encode-mysql-results)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
$return_arr = Array();

$query = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['query']);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM recent_tags where query like '%" . $query . "%'"); 

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    array_push($return_arr,$row);
}

echo json_encode($return_arr);
```

Comment: seconded ....
call fetch_array on the result which contains the query result you want..

Comment: this works fine..but can I add LIMIT 0, 20  to the above query ?

Answer (score 3):

Probably not the route you will go but I'll give this answer for completeness or just because I find it interesting:

There is also the possibility to let the database generate the JSON for you. mysqludf.org have a set of MYSQL user defined functions for JSON [available here](http://www.mysqludf.org/). Below is an example of converting a few fields to JSON:

```
select json_array(
   customer_id
   ,first_name
   ,last_name
   ,last_update
   ) as customer
from   customer 
where  customer_id =1;
```

If you have a lot of data to convert this may perhaps prove to be more scalable.

Comment: Probably not more scalable to do this in the database, IMHO, because web frontends are (in general) easier to scale than relational databases.

Comment: link is dead. do you know of a mirror or alternative? Otherwise, just delete the answer please.