# Mysql Query output into var data [,,,] array

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

How do i go ahead to output mysql row to a var array like this

```
 var data = [

            {"name" : "mysql data", "hvalue" : mysql data number },

        ];
```

all the possible mysql rows not just 1

Comment: use json to convert your php arrays

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like just altering the array you are building out...
So you can encode your db result

```
$sth = mysqli_query("SELECT ...");
$rows = array();
while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
    $rows[] = $r;
}
print json_encode($rows);//will return your desired data
```

The function json_encode needs PHP >= 5.2 and the php-json package - as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7318191/enable-json-encode-in-php)

NOTE: mysql is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, use mysqli extension instead http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php.

Comment: the mysql row has more columns than needed about 10 columns but i only need the "username" and for the chance it is calculated in php with

Comment: $chance=round(100*$sumvalue/$cb,1);

Comment: i hope changing  your select query to get only those specific columns you need would do the job

Comment: $rs = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `game".$cg."` GROUP BY `userid` ORDER BY `id` DESC"); is my query

Comment: why are you selecting all, change it to get only the name and hvalue.

Comment: because I need more than that to calculate the percentage $chance=round(100*$sumvalue/$cb,1);                                           $sumvalue = $row["value"];
$sumvalue=round($sumvalue,2);                                                         $cb = fetchinfo("cost","games","id",$cg);

Comment: its better if you can do the calculation in db query itself. you can open a new question if you need to get help in building the query. thanks

Comment: how do i then get that $rows into my original var data

Comment: json_encode($rows); this will return it, you can assign it any where you want

Comment: any chance you could help with the query?

Comment: i made my sql query but now how do i get the sql query into the actual var data, and format it

Comment: $sth = mysql_query("SELECT username, (SUM(value)/COUNT(value))*100 FROM game".$cg." GROUP BY userid ORDER BY id DESC");