# How can I json_encode the results of this query?

Tags: php, codeigniter, json

```
foreach($hello_world as $key=>$product_id) {
if(in_array($key,$exclude))continue;

$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM product where modelNumber = '$product_id'");
if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
foreach($query->result() as $row) {
    echo $row->name;
    }
}
}
```

Can someone give me advice as to how I would json encode the results of this query?
Thanks

Comment: **Warning** your code appears to be susceptible to sql injection attacks.

Comment: tried casting the result object as an array and passing it to json_encode()?

Comment: This question seems similar, and the first answer seems pertinent; if you have more specific needs perhaps you could update your question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383631/json-encode-mysql-results

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$data = array();
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM product where modelNumber = '$product_id'");
if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
foreach($query->result() as $row) {
    $data[$row->id] = $row->name;
    }
}
$json = json_encode($data);
```