# MySQL data to JSON via PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json

Basically idea is to grab data from MySQL table and transform it to JSON.

This is how database table looks:

[image]

And this how should output be:

```
[
   {"group1":[
               {"val":"somevalue"},
               {"val":"somevalue"}
             ]
   },
   {"group2":[
               {"val":"somevalue"},
               {"val":"somevalue"}
             ]
   },
   {"group3":[
               {"val":"somevalue"}
             ]
   }
]
```

My PHP script looks like this, for now:

```
$arr = [];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM thetable WHERE section='sect1'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  // ???
}

echo json_encode($arr);
```

My main issue is how to output/sort data in "groups".

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Check out this SO post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383631/json-encode-mysql-results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
   $arr[$row['group']][] = array('val' => $row['value']);
}
```