# Send key search from my iPhone to MySQL using JSON

Tags: php, iphone, mysql, json

I've problem with using JSON in my iPhone app, In my app there is a search function to search in MySQL database and display the result in table view.
My Problem is how can i send the key search to the php page, and get a result to display it in table view.

Any tutorial can help,
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to create and host a php page which runs your MySQL query and returns the result as a JSON string. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383631/json-encode-mysql-results) is how to do that.

As for the iPhone app, you want to look at [NSMutableURLRequest](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html). [Here](http://mobileorchard.com/tutorial-json-over-http-on-the-iphone/) is a tutorial on how to use it. In the tutorial replace the json url with the url of your php file.