# convert mysql result to json with correct types

Tags: php, mysql, json

I know how to get a mysql-row and convert it to json:

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=1"));
echo json_encode($row); // it's an ajax-call
```

but:

the db-row has different types like int, float, string.
by converting it using json_encode() all results are strings.

Is there a better way to correct the types than this:

```
$row['floatvalue1'] = 0+$row['floatvalue1'];
$row['floatvalue2'] = 0+$row['floatvalue2'];
$row['intvalue1'] = 0+$row['intvalue1'];
```

I would like to loop through the keys and add 0 because:

- first coding rule: DRY - dont repeat yourself

but i can't because:

- row has also other types than numbers (string, date)
- there are many columns
- design is in dev, so columns-names often changes

Thanks in advance and excuse my bad english :-)

**EDIT** (to answer the comment-question from Casimir et Hippolyte):

I call this php-code using ajax to get dynamically sql-values. in my javascript-code i use the results like this:

```
result['intvalue1'] += 100;
```

lets say the json-result of intval1 is 50, the calculated result is:

"50100", not 150

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: in this case cast your values in the javascript code: parseInt, parseFloat.

Comment: same problem in javascript-code then. furthermore i waste traffic by sending unnecessary "-chars.

Comment: You can use [`mysqli_fetch_field()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-field.php) in a loop to get information about each column from your result set and use it to know if you need to convert the value to a number or keep it as string. But I think it's easier to convert the value to `int` or `float` (as needed) in the javascript, before using it.

Comment: Iterate through the object and convert accordingly. I'd use sscanf

Comment: `unnecessary "` :), it's nothing! and the problem is not the same in javascript because javascript has a native access to json objects.

Comment: @axiac good point with mysqli_fetch_field(). There are MANY columns in this result-row, with different types like string, date, int, float, manually converting isnt a solution. please read my question till end :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The code below is just a proof of concept. It needs encapsulation in a function/method and some polishing before using it in production (f.e. call `mysqli_fetch_field()` in a loop and store the objects it returns before processing any row, not once for every row).

It uses the function [`mysqli_fetch_field()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-field.php) to get information about each column of the result set and converts to numbers those columns that have numeric types. The values of [`MYSQLI_TYPE_*`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.constants.php#constantmysqli-type-decimal) constants can be found in the documentation page of [Mysqli predefined constants](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.constants.php).

```
// Get the data
$result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=1");
$row    = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

// Fix the types    
$fixed = array();
foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
    $info = mysqli_fetch_field($result);
    if (in_array($info->type, array(
            MYSQLI_TYPE_TINY, MYSQLI_TYPE_SHORT, MYSQLI_TYPE_INT24,    
            MYSQLI_TYPE_LONG, MYSQLI_TYPE_LONGLONG,
            MYSQLI_TYPE_DECIMAL, 
            MYSQLI_TYPE_FLOAT, MYSQLI_TYPE_DOUBLE
    ))) {
        $fixed[$key] = 0 + $value;
    } else {
        $fixed[$key] = $value;
    }
}

// Compare the results
echo('all strings: '.json_encode($row)."\n");
echo('fixed types: '.json_encode($fixed)."\n");
```

Comment: thank you! That's the answer. Now i only have to change this snippet for converting more than one result. But this will lead me to the best way to solve my problem. Thx again.

Comment: Thanks for this. I dont see where $result is coming from on line 7 of the code though.  Is that a typo?

Comment: @TimSands Indeed, variable `$result` was missing. I guess I removed it by mistake when I put the code fragment into the answer (I thought it was used in a single place and inlined it). I fixed it now.

Answer (score 0):

If you're simply trying to make sure that your values are operable with respect to their type, you need to first cast their type correctly.

Unless you need them server-side, I would just pass-on the json directly to the front-end and do the work there.

In Javascript, you could make an attempt at casting the numbers like so:

```
function tryNumber(string){

    return !isNaN( parseInt(string) ) ? parseInt(string) : string;

}

function tryDate(string){

    return !isNaN( new Date(string).getTime() ) ? new Date(string) : string;

}

tryNumber('foo'); // "hello"
tryNumber('24'); // 24
tryDate('bar'); // "bar"
tryDate('December 17, 1995'); // "Sun Dec 17 1995 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT)"
```

These two lines attempt to cast the values as a [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)/[Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Number). If they can't be cast, they will remain [String](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String)'s.

Comment: this is a good way. my problem is, i use the json-results in more than one js-file (2-times clientside, one file server-side). i dont want to deliver wrong-parsed results from the sql-call and convert it at many other places. A php-solution directly after getting sql-results will be the better way.

Comment: @MarcelEnnix Fair enough. Axiac's answer is probably better for your needs then.

Answer (score 0):

something like

```
$row['floatvalue1'] = reset( sscanf ( $row['floatvalue1']  , "%f" ));
$row['floatvalue2'] = reset( sscanf ( $row['floatvalue2']  , "%f" ));
$row['intvalue1'] = reset( sscanf ( $row['intvalue1']  , "%d" ));
json_encode($row);
```

Comment: thx for this. But i cannot do this manually. There are MANY columns, and  the columns-names will change in type and name the next months, because the project using this ajax-call is in dev by more than one person.

Answer (score 0):

A MySQLi OO version based on @axiac's answer, that produces a JSON array ($jsnAll) containing all records. In this code snippet, the method FixSQLType is called to fix a row. Note, it should be wrapped in a try{}catch{} block and "objMySQLi" has already been instantiated:

```
         $lcAllRows = array();

         // Make an SQL SELECT statement 
         $SQL = "SELECT * FROM $lcName WHERE $lcWhere";

         // Run the query
         $this->sqlResult =  $this->objMySQLi->query($SQL);

         // Fetch the result
         while( $row = $this->sqlResult->fetch_assoc()){
             $lcCount = count($lcAllRows) ;

             // Call to fix, row 
             $fixedRow = $this->FixSQLType($row);
             $lcAllRows[$lcCount]= $fixedRow;
         }

         $jsnAll = json_encode($lcAllRows);
```

The FixSQLType method. This is almost identical to @axiac's answer, except for the call to $this->sqlResult->fetch_field_direct($i). "fetch_field" seemed to get itself lost, using "fetch_field_direct" overcame that problem.

```
    private function FixSQLType($pRow){
    // FROM https://stackoverflow.com/a/28261996/7571029

    // Fix the types    
    $fixed = array();
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($pRow as $key => $value) {
        $info = $this->sqlResult->fetch_field_direct($i);
        $i++;

        if (in_array($info->type, array(
                MYSQLI_TYPE_TINY, MYSQLI_TYPE_SHORT, MYSQLI_TYPE_INT24,    
                MYSQLI_TYPE_LONG, MYSQLI_TYPE_LONGLONG,
                MYSQLI_TYPE_DECIMAL, 
                MYSQLI_TYPE_FLOAT, MYSQLI_TYPE_DOUBLE
        ))) {
            $fixed[$key] = 0 + $value;
        } else {
            $fixed[$key] = $value;
        }

    }

    return $fixed;
}
```