# How to alert ajax response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I've read dozens of related posts, but I still can't get this to work.

I want to alert the response in jquery I get from PHP.

PHP:

```
$msg=array();

    if(empty($whatever)){
        $msg['cenas']="Não há contas";
    }else{
        $msg['cenas']="Há contas";
    };

    echo json_encode($msg);
```

JS:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'myscript.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response){
       alert(response.cenas);
    }
});
```

PHP is echoing

> {cenas: "Há contas}"
>   But I can't get it to alert in JS.

Comment: using firebug or chrome developer tools log the alert instead as `console.log(response)`. That will reveal your entire object response and should let you see what's wrong.

Comment: @HarveyA.Ramer console.log(response) returns "success"

Comment: That means, I believe, that you are just returning a string from your myscript.php file on success. In that case, you'll need to modify it to return an object to do what you're trying to do. This might be instructive: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8649621/returning-a-json-object-from-php-in-ajax-call

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The php should echo back `{"cenas": "Há contas"}`, but what did you get in the alert? Did you get an undefined? If so, try to use `jQuery.parseJSON` before alert. e.g:

```
$.ajax({
    url:"myscript.php",
    dataType: "json",
    success:function(data){
       var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
       alert(obj.cenas);
    }
});
```

Comment: That's right, I get undefined. With your recommendation, the success function, is never executed, therefore, no alert.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$.ajax({
    url:"myscript.php",
    dataType: "json",
    success:function(data){
       alert(data.cenas);
    }
});
```

You have a syntax error.

Check out the [Docs for $.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: Response/data doesn't matter. They're just parameter names. They're arbitrary. You could name it x and it'd be fine

Comment: Wicked, I'll take that out. Wasn't 100% sure.

Answer (score 0):

You should tell jQuery to expect (and parse) JSON in the response (although jQuery could guess this correctly...) and you should write your javascript correctly:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'myscript.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response){
       alert(response.cenas);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I've just edited my question. I do include dataType: 'json' in the ajax call

Comment: @NunoNogueira Check the differences between your and my ajax call (parenthesis for the function, quoting strings, etc.).

Comment: I dit that, I get undefined