# return tables rows in json and print

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I am trying to return ajax response in json, but when I print it in log it gives null even tables has rows,
 my php code is:

```
if(isset($_GET['proid'])){
    $projid = $_GET['proid'];
    include(db.php);
    $res = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM data WHERE project_id LIKE '%$projid%'");      
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) 
    {
      $dataarray[] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($dataarray);
}
```

ajax :

```
$.ajax({
        url : 'getRecStudy.php',
        type : 'GET',           
        data : {proid:study},
        success : function(data) {
            $('#tbody').empty();
            $("#tbody").append(data);
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
```

whats wrong?

Comment: What is your console data

Comment: Try die(json_encode($dataarray));

Comment: Can you add `echo json_last_error();`

Comment: in php file debug line by line, echo exit $variables at each line and hit 
getRecStudy.php?proid=study in url. Dont dubug ajax response.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8649621/returning-a-json-object-from-php-in-ajax-call Check with this.

Also use dataType: 'json', in your ajax call

Comment: no... nothing works

Answer (score 1):

I find no issue in your code except varibales. You need to debug the code in php file

```
if(isset($_GET['proid'])){
    echo $_GET['proid'] . " is proid";
    $projid = $_GET['proid'];
    include(db.php);
    echo "db connected";
    $res = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM data WHERE project_id LIKE '%$projid%'");      
    echo "result fetched";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) 
    {
      $dataarray[] = $row;
      echo "inside while";
    }
    echo json_encode($dataarray);
    print_r($dataarray);
    exit;
}
```

after all this hit `http://yourdomain.com/yourfile.php?proid=correctvalue`

You will get the bug.

Comment: can you give me any example link of ajax json example?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8649621/returning-a-json-object-from-php-in-ajax-call

Comment: it is still giving null @kishore

Comment: @VishalBorade null values wont print by the procedure i explained above, it  would echo string, error or blank provided you hit `http://yourdomain.com/yourfile.php?proid=correctvalue` correct url in browser not through ajax. 

Before calling ajax make sure your php file works properly through (non-ajax)

Comment: It was problem with connection string, when i wrot full connection string it gave me result. i dont knw why... bdw Thanks.

Comment: Glad to know the issue is solved. If somehow my answer helped you then give it a vote. Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

use  parseJSON method in success function like this

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( data );

alert( obj.name ); // For example name is a key
```

Comment: even if we dont parse, it  would still log some json encoded data not "null" value. Its loggin "null" value so parsing null json won't produce correct parsed value.