# Android - JSON / GSON Parsing

Tags: android, json, parsing, iteration, gson

My server returned the following string using the jsonencode() in the php code after sending a POST passing variables for the query.

{"distance":"0.00194210443015968","usrlat":"38.5817","usrlong":"-77.3245","globalid":"245"}{"distance":"4.94445650874035","usrlat":"38.6501","usrlong":"-77.2975","globalid":"233"}{"distance":"4.94445650874035","usrlat":"38.6501","usrlong":"-77.2975","globalid":"242"}

Code:

```
        try 
        { etc.. connection details..

            request = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream()); 
            request.write(parameters); 
            request.flush(); 
            request.close();             
            String line = "";                
            //Convert response to a string
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()); 
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr); 
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) 
            { 

                sb.append(line + "\n");

            } 
            // Response from server will be stored in response variable.                 
            response = sb.toString(); 

            //try parse the string to a JSON object
            try{

                jObject = new JSONObject(response);                 

            }catch(JSONException e){...
```

Background - This simple bit of code has produced a jObject which holds only the first element (object) from response.  I have tried changing the reponse to an jArray by inserting square brackets before and after, however the elements (objects) from the response are not seperated by a comma.  Considered interating through the response to insert comma's however the same root problem exists... parsing and interation.  Additionally, I have created a class with properties according to the response.  No luck there because the same root problem exist...Parsing and iteration.  I have scoured the net, only to discover that JSON is an extremely easy and lite weight alt to XML.  I have visted my local book store to discover that JSON is not a book worthy topic...yet.  Finally, I have turned to GSON for some clarity.

Question - Using JSON or GSON how do I deserialize  and iterate through the response to create useable objects in my android application?  Am I asking the right question in my search for a solution?

Comment: Here is an example http://thegeekyland.blogspot.com/2015/11/serializing-and-deserializing-json-from.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically hit on your issue - that the text is not a valid JSON array.  So you have two options:

1. Preprocess the JSON to make it a valid JSON array
2. Read each line one by one and create a JSONObject for each line, then manually add each object to a JSONSArray or a plain old java array or collection

FYI - This assumes you have no control over the server side.  If you do, change that code to make it a valid JSON array

Comment: mjmarsh thanks for the reponse.  I am a newbie no doubt.  Prepocessing brings me to iteration.  the response is all concated.  Would love to bypass the JSONArray still need iteration through string right?.  Finally, the server is on a hosted platform, have reviewed the ini. Is the jsonencode() adjustable on mySQL?

Comment: I have changed the server output to [{"distance":"0.00194210443015968","usrlat":"38.5817","usrlong":"-77.3245","globalid":"245"}][{"distance":"4.94445650874035","usrlat":"38.6501","usrlong":"-77.2975","globalid":"233"}][{"distance":"4.94445650874035","usrlat":"38.6501","usrlong":"-77.2975","globalid":"242"}]            Additionally, I have included jArray = new JSONArray(response); I have tried an iterative for loop but only pulls in the first array.

Comment: mjmarsh - THANK YOU.  I modified the output of the server.  I used the following link to add each proper JSONObject returned to a proper formatted JSON Array.  It was manageable to do it at the server than modify in Java.  I used http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383631/json-encode-mysql-results to create the proper array.  I used http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ to validate the response.  Now I will use either JSON or GSON in the app.  Thanks Again!