# jQuery flot, MySQL count rows for each day

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, rows, flot

I've table for hits that contains of 2 fields

```
id    time(TIMESTAMP)
1     2012-05-03 08:56:17
2     2012-04-26 03:22:20
3     2012-05-03 08:56:17
```

How can I count how many rows for each day for example for the past 10 days?

I mean what is the right query for it that produces:

2012-05-03 => 25 hits
2012-05-05 => 55 hits
etc

Also, how can i arrange the returned array as jQuery flot array ?

any answers / articles regarding my questions would be great help

Thank you

Comment: this what i've so far:
"select count(id) as count, DATE(time) as hitday from hits group by hitday"
and works fine, it shows day date and number of hits

Answer (score 2):

You want to use a Group By on the date field
something like

```
select count(*), dateField from tablename 
group by dateField
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I'd do it:

```
select count(id), DATE(time) as hitday from yourtable group by hitday
```

And regarding your jQuery thing, I am not very sure if I understand it or not. You want mysql to generate a jQuery parsable array for you? For that you definitely need to have a kinda middle man like php.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383631/json-encode-mysql-results) is another thread which shows you how a select result is converted to json using php.

Comment: Thanks for answer and no mysql won't generate the arrays for jquery flot, actually php does that by exporting special array from mysql returned array as json encode, but am not that good at it

Comment: your link is kinda weird :), please check it