# Google Pie Charts and PHP

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, json, google-visualization

I would like to have a Google pie chart on my website. The pie chart would be filled with data from the database. I was loooking at some examples at https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/php_example, but I'm lost when it comes to the JSON format.

Here are some examples:

```
 <html>
   <head>
<!--Load the AJAX API-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

// Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});

// Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
  var jsonData = $.ajax({
      url: "getData.php",
      dataType:"json",
      async: false
      }).responseText;

  // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);

  // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, {width: 400, height: 240});
}

</script>
</head>

<body>
  <!--Div that will hold the pie chart-->
  <div id="chart_div"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the snippet where I get lost (getData.php):

```
 <?php 

// This is just an example of reading server side data and sending it to the client.
// It reads a json formatted text file and outputs it.

 $string = file_get_contents("sampleData.json");
 echo $string;

// Instead you can query your database and parse into JSON etc etc

 ?>
```

I have data stored in a database and not in JSON format. How do I work with the JSON format using MySQL database queries? If you have some examples or demos, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to do would be to have a look at the PHP manual about the [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) method. It provides examples on how to generate JSON with PHP.

Here is a short example from [another similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383631/json-encode-mysql-results):

```
// Get your data from DB
$sth = mysql_query("SELECT ...");
// Create an array
$rows = array();
// Loop over the DB result and add it to your array
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
    $rows[] = $r;
}
// Use json_encode() to turn the array into JSON
print json_encode($rows);
```

If you need to rename your database columns, so that your JSON-data get other names on the properties than those used in your DB, you can use `AS` in your SQL.

```
SELECT blog_title as title ...
```

Comment: Thanks for help. Do I have to set labels inside json or in the options of api?

Comment: @extra90 I believe the name of the properties in you JSON-data will be used as labels on the chart, if that is what you mean?

Comment: I was looking documenation for google charts and json has to be right json format. json_encode is not enough. Do you have any experiences?

Comment: @extra90 Don't have any experience of it, but if you describe what your JSON will have to look like, I'm sure we can set something up using `json_encode()`, it should be sufficient.

Comment: It has to be something like that: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/php_example

Answer (score 0):

just echo php result in
`var data = new google.visualization.DataTable([<?php echo $result ;?>]);`

u will get data from database as per as 
below format

```
             ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
                      ['Work',     11],
                      ['Eat',      2],
                      ['Commute',  2],
                      ['Watch TV', 2],
                      ['Sleep',    7]
```

i think it's useful to u ,i am use same logic in heat map