# PHP - MySQL results to JSON

Tags: php, mysql, json

I'm trying to understand how to convert MySQL results to a JSON format so that I can then use this JSON later on with Javascript to build a HTML table. However my code just produces lot's of null values and I don't yet understand why.

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM Customers");

$test = json_encode($result);

print $test;
```

Output:

```
{"current_field":null,"field_count":null,"lengths":null,"num_rows":null,"type":null}
```

I have, for example, fields such as "CustomerID" and "Name", and even they don't show up in the JSON result.

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13945071/create-json-object-by-php-from-mysql-result

Comment: not sure if you are aware, when using 'json_decode', using a second parameter of 'true' will force the conversion to arrays rather than objects. i.e. $fooArray = json_decode($json, true);. it may save some hassle.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM Customers");   
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    $test[] = $row; 
print json_encode($test);
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. It shows the first customer in the database, is there some way I can loop through it to show all the customers?

Comment: Done. Try to use now.

Comment: for my setup I was doing it different this may help someone down the road `$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "password", "db");    
$results = $link->query($sql);
while ($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) 
    $resultArray[] = $row; 
echo "<pre>" . json_encode($resultArray, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT) . "</pre>";
`