# JSON encode mySQL results clarification

Tags: php, mysql

I am triyng to encode mySQL to JSON. I have tried this popular link
[JSON encode MySQL results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383631/json-encode-mysql-results) but the answer didn't work for me. I'll appritiate your help.

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<body>

<?php
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","Theory");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT `questions`.`questionID` AS question,
                                        `questions`.`questionText` AS questionText,
                                        `questions`.`categoryID` AS categoryID,
                                        `answers`.`answerID` AS answerID,
                                        `answers`.`answerText` AS answerText,
                                        `answers`.`isTrue` AS isTrue
                                 FROM `questions`,`answers`
                                 WHERE `questions`.`questionID`=`answers`.`questionID`");

    if (!$result)
    {
        die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }

   $rows = array();
   while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   $rows[] = $r;
   }
   print json_encode($rows);

    mysqli_close($con);
    ?>

</body>
</head>
```

I am getting :"[]"
Sorry if I am doing something stupid, I am new to php.

Comment: You're mixing and matching `mysql` and `mysqli`. Is `mysql_fetch_assoc()` a typo?

Comment: @JasonMcCreary It is not a typo, it is ignorance. Please explain what did I do wrong.

Comment: You should not be using `mysql_fetch_assoc` on a `mysqli` connection.

Comment: @tadman what should I use in this case and why mysql_fetch_assoc is not appropriate?

Comment: `mysqli` and `mysql`, despite their name similarities, are two totally different libraries and have nothing in common internally. Always check [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) for the correct methods to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing and matching the `mysql` and `mysqli` libraries.

If you are using `mysqli` (which the rest of your code is), you need to use the [`mysqli` functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php). In this case [`mysqli_fetch_assoc()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php):

```
while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $rows[] = $r;
}
```

**Note:** As an aside, I'd encourage you to use the `mysqli` [Object Oriented](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/object-oriented-php-for-beginners/) style.

Comment: `mysql` is the *original* and is now deprecated (PHP 5.5). `mysqli` is the newer, *improved* extension.

Comment: `mysql*` are depreciated in php newer version so try to avoid these functions instead you can use  `PDO`

Comment: Just for completeness, [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php) is another database extension that supports more databases platforms than just MySQL. Simply put, you could consider it a *generic* database extension that provides greater flexibility.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe try:

```
$rows = array();
$i = 0;
while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $rows[$i] = $r;
    $i++;
}
print json_encode($rows);
```

Or maybe:

```
$rows = array();
while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    array_push($rows, $r);
}
print json_encode($rows);
```

Comment: +1 for you but it would be more better if you brief the problem

Comment: @dianuj Thank, I guess I read right over her using mysql_fetch_assoc and not mysqli_fetch_assoc... whoops!

Answer (score 0):

This would probably be a lot more clear if you used the [object-oriented interface](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) to `mysqli`:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "root", "Theory");

$result = $mysqli->query("...");

while ($row = $result->fetch_object())
{
  ...
}

$result->close();
```

It's much harder to confuse methods when you're calling them directly on `$result`.