# getting values from mysql database into javascript in wordpress

Tags: javascript, mysql, wordpress

I am making a wordpress plugin. I am having trouble finding documentation on how to get values from a mysql database into a javascript in wordpress. I have seen examples when people are not using wordpress software, but i'm not sure if there is a better way or a need for better security because it is wordpress.

could anyone post a link to a helpful article or show a example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JSON to construct data representation in Javascript.

For that, I suggest you use a intermediary PHP page to control ACLs (i.e. restrict unauthorized access) and construct the JSON data/array.

A simple way to take MySQL data to JSON in PHP:  [JSON encode MySQL results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383631/json-encode-mysql-results)

More PHP JSON documentation here: http://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php