# Creating json string by customized variable values from table

Tags: php, json

I already have checked similar answer. But i have different issue here!

TO create googlce char I am creating json string by fetching data from table.
Table has only two rows. 
Here is how the json string is constructed:

```
 $result = $mysqli->query('SELECT * FROM view_name');

   $p= $mysqli->query('SELECT Index_val FROM view_name where ind_type=pcount');
 //echo "$p";

  $rows = array();
  $table = array();
  $table['cols'] = array(
    array('label' => 'pcount', 'type' => 'string'),
    array('label' => 'ncount', 'type' => 'number')
);
    /* Extract the information from $result */
    foreach($result as $r) {
      $temp = array();
      $temp[] = array('v' => (string) $r['ind_type']); 
      $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $r['Index_val']); 
      $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
    }

$table['rows'] = $rows;
```

Here only two values I need to fetch from database `pcount` and `ncount`. I dont want to use above procedeure.

What I want is to fetch the values of `pcount` and `ncount` from table manually, store in variable and construct the json string.

Like this :
`$p= $mysqli->query('SELECT Index_val FROM view_name where ind_type=pcount');` // Please correct if wrong
same way get get `ncount`.

Now how can I create above json string from this?
Resulting string will be like this:

```
{
    "cols":[
        {"label":"pcount","type":"string"},
        {"label":"ncount","type":"number"}],
    "rows":[
        {"c":
            [
            {"v":"pcount"},
            {"v":179}  // 179 is pcount
            ]
        },
        {"c":
            [
            {"v":"ncount"},
            {"v":285} //285 is ncount
            ]
        }
        ]
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSON encode MySQL results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383631/json-encode-mysql-results)

Comment: @ghaxx: I already have tried that method. But my above case I need some customization not in the way you gave link. I appreciate if you can show effort!

Comment: First of all, you need to understand how to work with mysqli.  You don;t just query and the data magicially populates into an array. Query just returnsa result set handle, which you must iterate over to get the data from the database.