# pull a table from SQL to create javascript array?

Tags: javascript, php, sql, ajax

I have data like this in a SQL table:

```
ID  |  Word  |  Count
1     word1     10
2     word2     5
```

I'd like to request this data from javascript (or an aJax call I guess?) and have it create an array. I also don't care about the ID#, but just the word and it's 'count.' Then I guess it would be a 2d array to store this info? Ie, word[0][0] would return "word1" and word[0][1] would return 10. Maybe there's a better way to do that last part, though. And then I'd like to sort these by count.

Thoughts?

EDIT:
It would seem as though I have the data getting piped back via PHP to JSON. However, how the heck do I get the data out of JSON and into a JS array?

```
$.getJSON('php_file.php', function(response) {
    // response is a JSON object that contains all the info from de sql query
    /* do your JS stuff here */
})
```

It's saying that response is false, and no more. What's the deal?

Comment: Fetch the data in php and process it in javascript or php for that matter.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSON encode MySQL results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383631/json-encode-mysql-results)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PHP file should look like this:

**PHP_FILE.PHP**

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY count [ASC|DESC]";
$result = execute_query($sql);
while($array = mysql_fetch_assoc($result));
echo json_encode($array);
```

And, then you have to make the AJAX call (for example, using JQuery)

```
$.getJSON('php_file.php', function(response) {
    // response is a JSON object that contains all the info from de sql query
    /* do your JS stuff here */
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, however I'm getting this error: Call to undefined function execute_query() in /Volumes/grayMac/creations/web/NSAgame/_v2/grab.php on line 16
Any ideas?

Comment: Ah ok nevermind, changed it to mysql_query and it worked. So now to figure out how to make use of a JSON object ;-)

Comment: I tried $.each(result, function(i, field){
      alert(field);
     }); but it won't give me anything

Comment: Try using `console.log(response)` to see the object in the js console (F12 in chrome). Then, if it looks like a numeric array use this notation `response[0]` and if it looks like key:value, then use this notation `response.key'. Got it?

Comment: As an example, for your response object `response[0].count` is equal to `10`.

Comment: @prismspecs Let me know if this was useful..

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at PHP's `json_encode` [in the manual](https://www.php.net/json_encode). It will allow you to convert a PHP array (which you'll populate from a database query) to a JSON object, which you will then output to the Ajax call from your Javascript.

Process:

- Javascript calls e.g. `results.php`
- `results.php` calls database and gets array
- `results.php` uses `json_encode` on said array and outputs it to the browser (`echo`)
- Javascript receives nice JSON array to use.

There's a nice example here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/383664/2812842