# How to extend a multidimensional array in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

if my code looks like...

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT id, name, color FROM fruits");
$list = array();
while($r = $result->fetch_array()) {
    $list[] = $r;
}
print json_encode(array('list' => $list));
```

the result is...

```
list[0].id = '1', list[0].name = 'apple', list[0].color = 'red';
list[1].id = '2', list[1].name = 'banana', list[1].color = 'yellow';
...
```

It's fine, but i need additional infos in the list.
How can i extend the arrays and get something like:

```
list[0].id = '1', list[0].name = 'apple', list[0].color = 'red', list[0].taste = 'sour';
list[1].id = '2', list[1].name = 'banana', list[1].color = 'yellow', list[0].taste = 'sweet';
...
```

This does not work:

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT id, name, color FROM fruits");
$list = array();
while($r = $result->fetch_array()) {
    $list[] = $r;
    $list[]['taste'] =  'sweet'; //DOES NOT WORK
    array_push($list,array("taste" => 'sweet')); //DOES ALSO NOT WORK
}
print json_encode(array('list' => $list));
```

Thank you!!!

Comment: `$list[]` should be something like `$list[$i]`?

Comment: @Class `$list[] = $value` is the same as "push $value to the array $list".

Comment: @h2ooooooo but `$list[]` 'increments' every time used so they won't be with the same array.

Comment: @Class I think you're misunderstanding. `$list[] = $value` is the same as `$list[count($list) - 1] = $value`. It's completely dynamic and you can use it multiple times to just add values.

Comment: This is an XY Problem.  Just add the static value to your SELECT clause. Or if you MUST use PHP, just use the union operator. `$list[] = $r + ['taste' => 'sweet'];`  See also: [JSON encode MySQL results](https://stackoverflow.com/q/383631/2943403)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `$list[] = $value` is the same as `array_push($list, $value)`. There's no such thing as `$list[]['key']`.

You should add it to the `$r` variable instead, before you add it to `$list`:

```
while($r = $result->fetch_array()) {
    $r['taste'] = 'sweet'; //DOES WORK!
    $list[] = $r;
}
```

---

If you already have `$list`, you can simply loop through and add it:

```
foreach ($list as &$array) {
    $array['taste'] = 'sweet';
}
unset($array); //remember to unset references
```

..or if you hate references:

```
foreach ($list as $key => $array) {
    $list[$key]['taste'] = 'sweet';
}
```

Comment: `There's no such thing as $list[]['key'].` ...that's not true.  That is valid syntax which will push a new, single-element row into `$list` with a key of `key` and a value of what ever is assigned.

Answer (score 0):

You need an intermediate variable

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT id, name, color FROM fruits");
$list = array();
while($r = $result->fetch_array()) {
 $r['taste'] =  'sweet'; //Modify an existing array

 $list[] = $r;


}
print json_encode(array('list' => $list));
```