# Javascript with PHP Foreach

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, foreach

So I am trying to use this plugin: http://w3widgets.com/responsive-calendar/

And the way the calendar is initialized and have events added is like so:

```
<script>
   <?php $today = date('Y-m'); ?>
   $( document ).ready( function() {
    $(".responsive-calendar").responsiveCalendar({
      time: '<?php echo $today; ?>',
      events: {
       "2014-04-30": {"number": 1, "badgeClass": "badge-warning", "url": "http://w3widgets.com/responsive-calendar"},
       "2013-04-26": {"number": 1, "badgeClass": "badge-warning", "url": "http://w3widgets.com"}, 
       "2013-05-03": {"number": 1, "badgeClass": "badge-error"}, 
       "2013-06-12": {}}
     });
    });
</script>
```

I want to generate the events with a foreach because the events are all stored in a database. I tried to do the following:

`events: {
   <?php foreach($events as $event): ?>
    "<?php echo $event->date; ?>"...`

But I get an error that says the `)` in the `($events as $event)` is unexpected.

How can I do this, I must be able to or the calendar has to disappear. Plain and simple.

**UPDATE**

If I `var_dump()` the `$events` I get the following string **(shortened to the first event!)**

`array(3) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#21 (5) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ["name"]=> string(17) "State Large Group" ["school"]=> string(9) "NHS Bands" ["date"]=> string(9) "4-16-2014" ["showHome"]=> string(1) "1" }...`

And If I `events: <?php echo json_encode($events); ?>` it doesn't encode in the correct order. It does:

```
events: [{"id":"1","name":"State Large Group","school":"NHS Bands","date":"4-16-2014","showHome":"1"},{"id":"2","name":"State Solo\/Ensemble","school":"NHS Bands","date":"4-26-2014","showHome":"1"},{"id":"3","name":"League Music Festival","school":"RVMS Bands","date":"4-29-2014","showHome":"1"}]  });
```

When it needs to be something like:

```
"2013-06-12": {}
```

Comment: Have you tried it with brackets?

<?php foreach($events as $event){ ?> "<?php echo $event->date; ?>"<?php } ?>

Comment: Maybe provide us with the actual code portion?

Comment: We can help you further if you show us where `$events` gets its contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
events: <?php echo json_encode($events) ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your database result to json and pass it to events.

[JSON encode MySQL results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383631/json-encode-mysql-results)