# How can I build this kind of format in my server side having v and f

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, charts, google-visualization

Hi I'm working in Google Orgchart and I am confuse how can I build this kind of format in my server side using php.

```
[
          [{v:'Mike', f:'Mike<div style="color:red; font-style:italic">President</div>'}, '', 'The President'],
          [{v:'Jim', f:'Jim<div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Vice President<div>'}, 'Mike', 'VP'],
          ['Alice', 'Mike', ''],
          ['Bob', 'Jim', 'Bob Sponge'],
          ['Carol', 'Bob', '']
        ]
```

so that I can put it on my client side to add it on my data.addRows(); like this in there example.

```
data.addRows([
          [{v:'Mike', f:'Mike<div style="color:red; font-style:italic">President</div>'}, '', 'The President'],
          [{v:'Jim', f:'Jim<div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Vice President<div>'}, 'Mike', 'VP'],
          ['Alice', 'Mike', ''],
          ['Bob', 'Jim', 'Bob Sponge'],
          ['Carol', 'Bob', '']
        ]);
```

[google orgchart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/orgchart#Data_Format)

**EDIT: ADD SOME DATA**

for example I have 3 columns in my mytable,

```
pcol  lcol   rcol
1       2     3

2       4      5
```

this is how i do in php to make it json

try{

```
      $cmd = $this->connection->prepare('SELECT pcol,lcol,rcol from mytbl');
      $cmd->execute();
      $records = $cmd->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

      return json_encode($records);


  }catch(){}
```

the reponse of my ajax is this.

```
 [{"pcol":"2","lcol":"4","rcol":"5"},{"pcol":"1","lcol":"2","rcol":"3"}]
```

and it's not working did not display the chart...because of the format.and I would like to know how can I achieve format having v and f.

something like this.

[{v:'2', f:'2'}, '1']

**EDIT: looping the result and building the format**

```
 foreach($records as $row) {
      $rowdata[]= '{v:'.$row['lcol'].',f:}'.$row['pcol'];

  }


  $return_data = array($rowdata);



  return json_encode($return_data);
```

but still it's not working. I'm having difficulties  in fomatting the data.
here is the output not working.

[["{v:4,f:}2","{v:2,f:}0"]]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: its called JSON: http://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSON encode MySQL results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383631/json-encode-mysql-results)

Comment: @Dagon,yes I know it's json but the format has 'v' an 'f' i don't know to build that

Comment: same way you create any other php array

Comment: @charlietfl,I will update my post,I will put some data

Comment: @charlietfl,how to ouotput like this [{v:'1', f:'1'}, '', 'A-8987']

Comment: can't just ask how to generate output without discussing what the input is

Comment: @charlietfl,I add now sample data please take a look

Comment: loop over the query results and create the necessary array by assigning the properties to appropriate db field value(s)

Comment: @charlietfl,I could not get the exact format, I updated my post

Comment: don't build json as a string in the php loop, it should be array

Comment: but how can I put v and f ?