# SQL Query to JavaScript Array

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql

I'm trying to make a video gallery using blueimp. https://github.com/blueimp
Unfortunately I'm not that skilled in MySQL and I'm wondering how I can get the return of a query with youtube URLs into a JavaScript array.
Example:

blueimp.Gallery([
        {
            title: 'Sintel',
            href: 'https://archive.org/download/Sintel/sintel-2048-surround_512kb.mp4',
            type: 'video/mp4',
            poster: 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8qdL.jpg'
        },
...

Thanks already, hope you can help.

Comment: What language are you using to execute the MySQL query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the PHP function `json_encode()` on your array to convert it to a javascript object.

You should do something like [what was done here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383631/json-encode-mysql-results)

```
$sth = mysqli_query("SELECT ...");
$rows = array();
while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
    $rows[] = $r;
}
print json_encode($rows);
```

You might need to do some work to assemble the array into the format that you want.  Do that within the while loop of the above mentioned code IE:

```
$sth = mysqli_query("SELECT ...");
$rows = array();
while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
    $rows[]['title'] = $r['title'];
    $rows[]['href'] = $r['href'];
}
print json_encode($rows);
```