# How to display user data in a label from mysql? xcode

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I am developing an app that connects to mysql database and uses user and password to login, this is working great, now i need to get other datas from this user and display it in a label. How I can get this datas from this user in the table and display them in a label?

My PHP file:

```
<?php
// Ghalia ALrajban
// 21 Dec 2011

if (isset($_GET["email"])  && isset($_GET["senha"]) ){
                $email = $_GET["email"];
                $senha = $_GET["senha"];
                $result = login( $email, $senha);
                echo $result;
                }

function makeSqlConnection()
{
$DB_HostName = "***.com";
$DB_Name = "***gou";
$DB_User = "***gou";
$DB_Pass = "***";

    $con = mysql_connect($DB_HostName,$DB_User,$DB_Pass) or die(mysql_error()); 

        mysql_select_db($DB_Name,$con) or die(mysql_error()); 

    return $con;
}

function disconnectSqlConnection($con)
{
    mysql_close($con);
}

function login($email, $senha)
{
    //require (FILE);
    $con = makeSqlConnection();

    $sql = "select * from usuario_log  where email = '$email' and senha = '$senha';";
    $res = mysql_query($sql,$con) or die(mysql_error());

    $res1 = mysql_num_rows($res);

    disconnectSqlConnection($con);

     if ($res1 != 0) {
        return 1;
    }else{
        return 0;
    }// end else


}// end of Function 

?>
```

My Login Button in my .m file:

```
    #pragma mark - BOTAO LOGIN
- (IBAction)loginButton:(id)sender {
    // Verificar e informar se os dados estao em branco.
    if([emailTextField.text isEqualToString:@""] || [senhaTextField.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
        UIAlertView *errorbranco = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Erro" message:@"Preencha todos os campos" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [errorbranco show];
    }

    //Verificar informacoes no banco de dados
    else{
        NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://peggou.com.br/login.php?email=%@&senha=%@", emailTextField.text, senhaTextField.text];
        NSData *dataURL = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]];
        NSString *strResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        //Informacoes Corretas
        if ([strResult isEqualToString:@"1"]) {
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"entrou" sender:self];
        }
        //Informacoes Incorretas
        else{
            UIAlertView *error = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Erro" message:@"e-mail ou senha invalidos" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
            [error show];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok this is horrible u want your tables dropped

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dataWithContentsOfURL` and return a json structure as described in the top answer here: [JSON encode MySQL results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383631/json-encode-mysql-results)

Use [NSJSONSerialization](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/index.html) to convert it back in the ios part.

But keep in mind that's bad to try to display >100 table rows at once, so please use paging (SQL: `limit PN*PS+1,PS`, where PN=page number, PS=page size), for your own sanity.