# Why should we use JSON for mysql fetching?

Tags: php, html, mysql, json, ajax

So i had setup a site which fetches mysql queries and get output json from PHP which then i put to use with js.

So it becomes a 5 step process.

> Query -> PDO Statement -> PHP Array -> JSON Strings -> JS Object or AJAX

Step 3-4-5 can be controversial as per developers choice.

I use JSON for mostly lower informative textual content which actually doesn't get valued among security concerns. But to manage a large textual content over ( > 100000) queries, its better to stick with mysql. Mysql is very native to PHP. So why shouldn't we just use php to perform same tasks that we make use for json.

I understand a major block would be ajax calling, but with advent of reactphp web server scripts, async calls can be made [[link]](https://github.com/reactphp/async).

If we can work out in 3 steps using PHP, then is there any absolute reason we should `use/recommend` JSON?Speed, flexibility, offline-nature?Anything else?

> Edit:

How can i reduce the steps to output my mysql query as JSON omitting php `json_encode` function? CAn it be done directly?

Comment: I'm confused. Are you saying you want to use MySQL directly in JS?

Comment: MYSQL in JSON i said.

Comment: You don't use JSON to do queries in mysql. Mysql is a DBMS and JSON is used to transmit data, you can not compare them to each other

Comment: And that, Sachin, is why I'm confused. You'd better show some code because it's hard to understand what you're currently doing. It makes no sense.

Comment: it's called a mysql client layer. Something has to have it, to talk the talk, walk the walk

Comment: something like this! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383631/json-encode-mysql-results

Comment: `I use JSON blah blah blah, But to manage blah blah, its better to stick with mysql`. WHAT ?

Comment: "why shouldn't we just use php to perform same tasks that we make use for json" — That doesn't many any sense. PHP is a programming language. JSON is a text based data format. You're comparing apples and trees.

Comment: @SachinKanungo I think you have misunderstood JSON, it is not used for `mysql fetching`. It is just a notation/format, which javascript can easily understand, so people use it for ajax mainly.

Comment: Neither i am comparing php nor i misunderstood JSON, the problem is i wanted ajax calling features where i can provide mysql query data in chunks. I used `json_encode` function from php for that purpose. That's what i am comparing. If anyway i can make direct ajax call with PHP would be great

Comment: That makes even less sense. Ajax specifically refers to using JavaScript to make an HTTP request from the browser without leaving the page. PHP doesn't even run in the browser.

Comment: @SachinKanungo "mysql query data" is not something Javascript can understand. That's why you have to convert it into a format that it CAN understand, e.g. JSON. You don't have to use JSON... you can use XML, CSV, or any number of arbitrary formats that you can invent yourself. But JSON is already natively supported by JS so it doesn't require extra processing on the client side. That's one of the main reasons it's used.

Comment: when did i said php runs in browser? i use php json_encode function to output mysql content. How come php run in browser relates

Comment: If at the rightmost end you have AJAX then how do you suggest filling the gap between MySQL and Javascript?

Comment: why don't we step back to your 5 Step process at the top. How would you **like** it to occur. Show it in your question as an [edit]

Comment: sir,i updated the post with question

Comment: I already answered this in my previous comment.

Comment: so you want a PHP array to stream back to javascript. Maybe take it up with the **W3C**

Comment: i have 10 columns in my mysql database which i want to update in browser with small chunks as output. All this process should be taken under AJAX calling(without browser reload). Thats what i wanted

Comment: well if there is no browser calling, there is always courier pigeon. Throughput is poor I hear

Comment: i edited the typo. it is without browser reload (Async Request to mysql DB)

Comment: that's cool. Then this is an AJAX how do I do it question then

Answer (score 1):

"mysql query data", or a PHP array, is not something Javascript can understand. That's why you have to convert it into a format that it CAN understand, e.g. JSON.

You don't have to use JSON... you can use XML, CSV, or any number of arbitrary formats that you can invent yourself. But JSON is already natively supported by JS so it doesn't require extra processing on the client side. That's one of the main reasons it's used.

Either way, you have to convert it *somehow*

Comment: got my support. And Steve's answer wasn't too shabby either.

Comment: So i did. Why do you think i am using mysql query directly in javascript. i did called `using php json encode funtion`. Though it's fine, i agree with edit.

Comment: My comment was asking what you WANT to do, not what you are doing currently. And from your edit "How can i reduce the steps to output my mysql query as JSON omitting php json_encode function? CAn it be done directly?" it sounds like you are wanting to do exactly that. Unfortunately, you can't.

Comment: that's more specific.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's coming

> 11.6 The JSON Data Type As of MySQL 5.7.8, MySQL supports a native JSON data type that enables efficient access to data in JSON
>   (JavaScript Object Notation) documents. The JSON data type provides
>   these advantages over storing JSON-format strings in a string column

:

[MySQL json doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html/)

Comment: a decent improvement, but let's not turn mysql into mongo

Comment: I certainly didn't downvote. I think we are all struggling to understand what the OP wants