# SyntaxError: missing ] after element list PHP, Jquery & Highcharts

Tags: php, jquery, highcharts

I am trying to write a script to produce a chart using HighCharts. I have an issue with a call to my data which is causing an error.

SyntaxError: missing ] after element list

This is the code I am using:

```
var data1 = [<?php
mysql_select_db($database_test, $con);
$query_result = sprintf("SELECT AName FROM Answers WHERE AName IS NOT NULL GROUP BY AName");
$result = mysql_query($query_result, $con) or die(mysql_error());


while ($row_result = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
?>

[<?php echo $row_result['AName'];?>],

<?php
}
?>
]
```

Trying to debug it in Firefox dev console it points to the above code as the cause. Can anyone see why it is falling over with the error "SyntaxError: missing ] after element list.

If I hard code the data it works fine.

Many thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: You will have an extra comma at the end, i.e. `[ [...], [...], [...], ]`.

Comment: Also, if `AName` is a string, you will need to wrap that code in quotes, e.g. `["<?php echo $row_result['AName'];?>"],`

Comment: @usandfriends great I think that fixed it

Comment: Need more details like contents of 'AName' column

Answer (score 1):

Add the coma before the array except for the first one, it will do the trick.

But also take a look at [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

```
var data1 = [<?php
mysql_select_db($database_test, $con);
$query_result = sprintf("SELECT AName FROM Answers WHERE AName IS NOT NULL GROUP BY AName");
$result = mysql_query($query_result, $con) or die(mysql_error());

$first = true;
while ($row_result = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    if($first) {
         $first = false;
    } else {
         echo ', ';
    }
    echo '[' . $row_result['AName'] . ']';
}
?>
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Per comments, it looks like `AName` is a alphanumeric string which needs to be wrapped in quotes.

```
<?php
    mysql_select_db($database_test, $con);
    $query_result = sprintf("SELECT AName FROM Answers WHERE AName IS NOT NULL GROUP BY AName");
    $result = mysql_query($query_result, $con) or die(mysql_error());
?>

var data1 = [
    <?php while ($row_result = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { ?>
        ["<?php echo $row_result['AName'];?>"], // <—— Wrap in quotes here
    <?php } ?>
];
```

Also, as [KyleK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32647700/2006429) pointed out, why aren't you using [`json_encode`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/383631)?

Answer (score 0):

first of you will create the php array of database value which is needed.
after this you will convert this it into json encode using j json_encode($array).
then use the $.each() function for creating the high chart array value.

$(document).ready(function(){

```
var array = [];
array.push('apple');
array.push('apple');
array.push('apple');
alert(array);
```

});