# How to get value of multiple rows and columns in one row ?

Tags: sql, sql-server, json

I have one table. Which name is student. There is three column.

```
Name Address Roll Age
X      A      1   20
Y      B      2   20
z      C      3   20
M      D      4   25
```

I want to collect all name and address whose Age is 20. I use this.

```
$sql = "select Name,Age from student where Age = 20";

while($data= sqlsrv_fetch_array($sql,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
 { 
   echo json_encode(data);
 }
```

By this i get just last row data that means

```
{"Name":X,"Address":A}
```

But i want like this

```
{"Name":X,"Address":A,"Name":Y,"Address":B,"Name":Z,"Address":C}
```

Comment: Maybe this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383631/json-encode-mysql-results

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code below, [reference here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php):

```
$jsonData = array();
while ($array = mysql_fetch_row($sql,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $jsonData[] = $array;
}
echo json_encode($jsonData);
```