# MySQL to JSON with array

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have a MySQL table containing data in the following form:

```
  set_id         ID of a set of items 
  country        country of origin of the set
  year           year of origin of the set
    item_id        ID of an item belonging to a set
    price          price of an item belonging to a set
    color          color of an item of a set
```

So imagine this sample data in MySQL:

```
SET                    ITEM
ID   COUNTRY    YEAR    ID    PRICE   COLOR
--   -------    ----   ----   -----   -----
1    USA        1872    1     $10     blue
1    USA        1872    2     $20     red
1    USA        1872    3     $25     green

2    Mexico     1902    4     $1      yellow
2    Mexico     1902    5     $2      orange

3    Canada     1920    6     $5      violet
```

I wish to create JSON output (or output that can be converted to JSON using PHP) that looks like ...

In "natural" form, these three items would look like this:

```
SET 1 -> {"set_id":"1","country":"USA","year":"1872","items":[{"item_id":"1","price":"$10","color":"blue",},{"item_id":"2","price":"$20","color":"red",},{"item_id":"3","price":"$25","color":"green",}]}

SET 2 -> {"set_id":"2","country":"Mexico","year":"1902","items":[{"item_id":"4","price":"$1","color":"yellow",},{"item_id":"5","price":"$2","color":"orange",}]}

SET 3 -> {"set_id":"3","country":"Canada","year":"1920","items":[{"item_id":"6","price":"$5","color":"violet",}]}
```

But for readability, I present the JSON as this:

```
SET #1
{
  "set_id":"1",
  "country":"USA",
  "year":"1872",
  "items" : [
    {
      "item_id":"1",
      "price":"$10",
      "color":"blue",
    },
    {
      "item_id":"2",
      "price":"$20",
      "color":"red",
    },
    {
      "item_id":"3",
      "price":"$25",
      "color":"green",
    }
  ]
}

SET #2
{
  "set_id":"2",
  "country":"Mexico",
  "year":"1902",
  "items" : [
    {
      "item_id":"4",
      "price":"$1",
      "color":"yellow",
    },
    {
      "item_id":"5",
      "price":"$2",
      "color":"orange",
    }
  ]
}

SET #3
{
  "set_id":"3",
  "country":"Canada",
  "year":"1920",
  "items" : [
    {
      "item_id":"6",
      "price":"$5",
      "color":"violet",
    }
  ]
}
```

So ... how can I fetch from MySQL and produce this JSON output?

Constraints:
- MySQL database fetch will be done in PHP using PDO methods.
- Output will be one JSON text for each set_id.

Comment: Have you tried some code yet? Show us what did you try and why it doesn't work like you expect.

Comment: Build up your data structure in PHP then json_encode them http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383631/json-encode-mysql-results

Comment: Ok. Did that. It works. Thanks.