# send an array from php to as3.0

Tags: php, arrays, actionscript-3, flash

I am building an air app in flash cs6 using as3. I need to send an array from php to flash as3.0
I wanted to create a "timeline" on my application.
I have a lot of reading various references, but not much help.
This is the code I use.
timeline.php file

```
require_once "connect.php";
$action = isset($_GET['action'])?$_GET['action']:'';
$body_nama = array();
$body_postingan = array();
$total_likers = array();
$id = array();
switch($action){
    case 'posting':
    posting();
    break;
    case 'like':
    like();
    break;
    case 'delet_ini':
    deletIni();
    break;
    case 'load_timeline':
    loadTimeline();
    break;
    case 'load_timeline_lama':
    loadTimelineLama();
    break;
}
function loadTimeline(){
    global $body_nama;
    global $body_postingan;
    global $total_likers;
    global $id;

    $query_total = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM timeline_posts";
    $result_total = mysql_query($query_total);
    $total = mysql_result($result_total,0);

    for ($i =0; $i<=9; $i++){
        $query_timline = "SELECT * FROM timeline_posts WHERE id = ('$total'-'$i')";
        $result = mysql_query($query_timline);
        while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
            $body_nama[$i] = htmlentities($data['timeline_name']);
            $body_postingan[$i] = htmlentities($data['timeline_post']);
            $id[$i] = htmlentities($data['id']);
            print "nama[$i]=$body_nama[$i]";
            print "postingan[$i]=$body_postingan[$i]";
            print "id[$i]=$id[$i]";
        }
    }
}
```

and here is as3.0 code

```
function loadTimeline(){
    var phpFileRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://localhost/social_media_1/timeline.php?action=load_timeline");
    var phpLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    phpLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
    phpLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onCompleteLoadTimeline);
    phpLoader.load(phpFileRequest);

    function onCompleteLoadTimeline(event:Event){

        trace (event.target.data.nama[0]);
        trace (event.target.data.postingan[0]);
        trace (event.target.data.id[0]);

    }
}
```

but I have error.

> TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.    at
>   Function/MasagiApp_fla:MainTimeline/loadTimeline/MasagiApp_fla:onCompleteLoadTimeline()[MasagiApp_fla.MainTimeline::frame6:52]
>     at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()    at
>   flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()     at
>   flash.net::URLLoader/onComplete()

please help me

Comment: I think you should move the `onCompleteLoadTimeline` function outside of the `loadTimeline` function.

Comment: thanks to a very quick response, but no change in output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not assemble your data into a string as you do it. In your case, the result is not a valid url encoded string (missing the &, for example) and it doesn't automatically convert into an array either as you expect it in your code.

JSON or XML is a better format to exchange data, especially when it has some kind of structure. I use the former for this answer.

Speaking of structure, distributing the data that belongs together over several arrays is a *bad* structure. Don't have many arrays with single properties, but one array instead, with objects in it that groups the properties together.

In your case, one object has the properties `name`, `posting` and `ID`, which would look something like this in JSON:

```
{
    "name":"foo",
    "posting":"bar",
    "ID":"123"
}
```

As you have many such objects, they are in an array:

```
[
    {
        "name":"foo",
        "posting":"bar",
        "ID":"123"
    },
    {
        "name":"foo000oo",
        "posting":"baAAaar",
        "ID":"456"
    }
]
```

This is what the body of the response from your server could look like.
In PHP, you have `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` and `json_encode()` to get your data from the database into a JSON representation [as you can see in this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/383631/4347580)

On the client side (and yes, @[Jonny Henly](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1241334/jonny-henly) is right hat you should not nest functions into each other!) you [JSON.parse()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/JSON.html#parse%28%29) the received string and get a generic As3 `Object` as a result:

```
function onCompleteLoadTimeline(event:Event)
{
    var result:Object = JSON.parse(event.target.data);

    trace (result[0].name);  // should give first name
}
```