# PHP format mysql result into json

Tags: php, mysql, json

I've been beating my head all day because of this.
[image]

[image]

How to convert the results from the image above into json format like this

```
{
        "name": "João Batista Da Silva Júnior",
        "y": "9.83",
        "drilldown": "João Batista Da Silva Júnior",
        "data": [
            [
                "assiduidade",
                10
            ],
            [
                "normas",
                9
            ],
            [
                "eficiencia",
                10
            ],
            [
                "relacionamento",
                10
            ],
            [
                "iniciativa",
                10
            ],
            [
                "visao",
                10
            ]
        ]
    }
]
```

}

I'm trying this code but it doesn't reproduce the format required.

```
    $info["aval"] = array();
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        extract($row);
        $info2 = ['name' => $auxiliar, 'y' => $media, 'drilldown' => $auxiliar, 'data' => [[$topico, floatval($nota)]]];
        $info["aval"][] = $info2;
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSON encode MySQL results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383631/json-encode-mysql-results)

Comment: you're not going to be able to do that with a simple loop/array build. none of your `data` values appear by themselves in the table, and will have to be extracted, and some of those values don't appear AT ALL.

Comment: Where does 9.83 come from, 'assiduidade', ...? None of these values relate to anything in the images. Also, don't post images. Copy the text into the question and format it as code.

Comment: The format is just an example of the structure, the `data` is actually the result from select on the second image.

Comment: @MarcB can you point me at least the idea on how to achieve this? I'm lost here because I don't know how to handle those multiple rows from avaliacaoTopico table.