# Join mysql tables and formatting json

Tags: mysql, json

Hi Guys is there is direct way to format data within sql query to avoid loops.
For example : 
Suppose there 2 tables as following 
tbl1(id,name,value)
tbl2(id,tbl1_id,name) // tbl1_id is primary key of tbl1

Now tbl2 can have multiple records with same tbl1_id.
Now how to get formatted data where I can get multiple records for tbl1 and then tbl2 array under id of tbl1 ?

Comment: What are your expected results?  Perhaps you are looking to use `group_concat`?

Comment: You do a JOIN, of course. In order of tbl1_id. Then you need to extract those data. In what language did you try to do that? And where's your code?

Comment: I guess this would be helpful ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383631/json-encode-mysql-results

Comment: Hi @sgeddes I was looking for json where from tbl1 lets say 3 records and under every record from tbl1 there will multiple records from tbl2 referencing tbl1. this is one to many ref for every record in tbl1 to tbl2 on tbl1_id column.