# Ajax : change button text according to flag value in database

Tags: ajax

i need to change button text from 'disable' to 'enable' or vice verse onclick depending on flag value in database which is 'on' or 'off'

i have tried to many ways using `javascript` and `jquery` but the Application methodology doesn't work with this , so i have found that the `Ajax` may bay the suitable way So any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ajax is just an asynchronous HTTP request you can perform from JavaScript (and, of course, JQuery). In fact, it stands for *Asynchronous JavaScript and XML*, even though JSON is preferred over XML recently.

Basically, what you could do with Ajax (using JQuery, for instance), is the following

```
$.get("/resource/returning/flag", function(data){
    if(data.flag == "on")
        $("button#your_button").html("disable");
    else
        $("button#your_button").html("enable");
});
```

Refer [here](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) for a more detailed API.

Comment: oki , that's seems helpful , but can you explain how can i pass something like that ( $.get("/serverName/databaseName/tableName/flag") ??

Comment: What do you mean with _pass_-ing?

Comment: in this snippet of code $.get("/resource/returning/flag", function(data)

Comment: i want to replace the "/resource/returning/flag"
with (server/database/column)

Comment: Ok, then you'll have to create a resource (say, a .php file) that connects to your database, fetches the wanted record with a query and returns it either as a JSON, a XML or whatever suits you best. See this example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383631/json-encode-mysql-results

Comment: thank you very much i'm really appreciating your effort :))