# MySql output to hierarchical JSON in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have a MySQL database, the content of which I need to serve as a JSON feed. It is a list of parameters, which have two set of attributes, Source and Target, with again have a set of attributes. I need the following structure:

```
Parameter: [
  Source: {
    operation: xxx,
    fc: xxx,
    address: xxx
  }
  Target: {
      topic: xxx
  }
  ],[
```

I'll admit I am weak in dealing with arrays in PHP, and I am at my wits end. My code looks like so:

```
class Parameter {
public $parameter = "";
}

class Join {
    public $Source = "";
    public $Target = "";
}

class Source {
    public $sourceOperation = "";
    public $fc = "";
    public $address = "";    
}

class Target {
public $topic = "";
public $targetOperation = "";
}

//Then we get the correct registers from the database
$sql_build_profile="SELECT * FROM DeviceProfiles WHERE DeviceID = '".$q."'  AND RegisterID IN (".$ParameterArray.") ORDER BY RegisterID ASC";
$result_build_profile = mysqli_query($con,$sql_build_profile);

//Time to build the output
while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result_build_profile)) {

$targetString = $UniqueString."/".$row1['RegisterID'];

$source = new Source();
$source->sourceOperation = $row1['SourceOperation'];
$source->fc = $row1['FC'];
$source->address = $row1['Register'];

$target = new Target();

if ($row1['SourceOperation'] == "Write"){

$target->targetOperation = "subscribe";

} else {
    $target->targetOperation = "";
}

$target->topic = $targetString;

$join = new Join();
$join->Source = $source;
$join->Target = $target;

$parameter = new Parameter();
$parameter->parameter = $join;

 echo ($i>0?',':'').json_encode($parameter, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

}
```

which gets me this JSON output:

```
"parameter": {
    "Source": {
        "sourceOperation": "Read",
        "fc": "3",
        "address": "16383"
    },
    "Target": {
        "topic": "09265eb2455845552e4df3c9a20a8eed\/1",
        "targetOperation": ""
    }
}
}{
"parameter": {
    "Source": {
        "sourceOperation": "Write",
        "fc": "16",
        "address": "16383"
    },
    "Target": {
        "topic": "09265eb2455845552e4df3c9a20a8eed\/2",
        "targetOperation": "subscribe"
    }
}
}
```

missing the single leading  "[]" and ",". I am quite sure it's to do with making an array out of the data, but I can't figure it out. I've looked at other questions, but not been able to apply them to my example - likely due to limited understanding.

Thanks for you help.

Comment: the json included in the post is invalid ... eg not produced by a json_encode php statement. Show the code which produced that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSON encode MySQL results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383631/json-encode-mysql-results)

Comment: You can't have associative arrays in JSON. They will always be converted as objects. If you just want to convert the result to json, there's no need to create structures, just build one mutli dimensional array and convert it with json_encode().

Comment: @YvesLeBorg The json_encode statement is included, please scroll down in the code box.

Comment: thanks for your input. I changed the code so now it actually gives off a valid JSON data structure. My problem has now changed in that I want to add data to this array - having issues with that. Will start a separate questions. Thanks for your help.