# Send mysql data as json feed to another developer

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have the following code;

```
// check phone exist or not
$query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE phone_number=".$phone;
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if($count!=0){
    $error = true;
    $phoneError = "Provided Phone Number($phone) is already in use.";
}
```

How can i send the result of the query as json feed to my colleague who we are working on the same project?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSON encode MySQL results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383631/json-encode-mysql-results)

Comment: `How can i send the result of the query as json feed to my colleague who we are working on the same project?` weird??

Comment: `$error = [];
if($count!=0){
    $error['status'] = 'fail';
    $error['message'] = "Provided Phone Number($phone) is already in use.";
}else{
 $error['status'] = 'success';
}

echo json_encode($error);`

Comment: @AlivetoDie, great assistance. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create an array, where you can add status like `fail/success` and corresponding messages based on that.

A sample code is given below:-

```
$final_message = []; 
if($count > 0){ 
  $final_message['status'] = 'fail'; 
  $final_message['message'] = "Provided Phone Number($phone) is already in use."; 
}else{ 
  $final_message['status'] = 'success'; 
} 
echo json_encode($final_message);
```